# When do I use #include<string>?

Tags: c++

I know that we use  `#include<iostream>` for cout function.
However, I'm curious when we need to use `#include<string>`.
Im a student taking C++ class.
Thanks.

Comment: See http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/string for a list of things that `<string>` contains. Also, make a bookmark of that website in case you want to look up similar things later.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Include it whenever you need something from that header. [Here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/string) you can find a list of things that you need to `#include <string>` for.